# How to configure retrieving folder once when camel start?

Tags: apache-camel

My requirement as below,

Starting camel,then processing all of the files with file component ,which is located some folder once.this route is just used once.

So how to configure with spring DSL?

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1):

Split your requirement as follow

> Starting camel

- Your research item, cover this will be off-topic in stackoverflow

> processing all of the files with file component

- Use `file` component by `from`, i.e. `from("file://...")`

> is located some folder once

- Set a proper parent directory and then use `recursive` option in `file` component to enable sub-directories lookup. For further control, you may check following options `minDepth`, `maxDepth`, `filterDirectory`, `filter`

> this route is just used once

- Use `repeatCount` option in `file` component to control fire count, i.e. `repeatCount=1`

---

Combine them together, you have

```java
from("file://path/to/parent/directory?repeatCount=1&recursive=true")
    ... // follow by your route logic
```